# MediatR multiple RequestHandlers

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, mediatr

I have a request which contains some information about order.

I have Rule sets for orders. When I send this request It should handle by all rule handlers and return results.
All handlers get same request object.

Can I send register multiple request handlers for mediatr ?

(I can't use notifications. They are fire forget. And I need return result)

Comment: Have you looked into whether Pipeline Behaviors will fit your needs? What do you mean by all rule handlers return results? Return to where? The next handler?

Answer (score 5):

> Can I send register multiple request handlers for mediatr?

No. From the docs:

> MediatR has two kinds of messages it dispatches:
>
> 1. Request/response messages, dispatched to a single handler
> 2. Notification messages, dispatched to multiple handlers

This is by design.

Send    = Tell someone a message (command)
Publish = Tell the world something happened (event)

Since mediatr works in-process, Requests (`Send()`) can also return a response.
And again, since mediatr works in-process, `Publish()` is not fire-and-forget (not by default at least).

Comment: I know how mediatr works but I need to extend it

Comment: @erenarslan no you appear to be missing the point... why not have a single request handler that loops through the ruleset. Update your question with more relevant code that explains why that's not feasible. Mediatr is not meant to "zip" results together for you. If you want to *send* multiple requests, you need to *send* multiple requests.

Comment: can you say what are mediatr oficial docs?

Comment: @galdin: Mashing it into a single handler, especially if the handlings get expanded over time, is an OCP violation. The clean approach would consist of defining each handling individually, without needing to maintain some sort of "list of handlings" that needs to be manually curated and not forgotten every time a new handling is added. Can this be done using reflection and something you've rolled yourself? Sure. But given how Mediatr scans your assembly for you and handles many things, asking if it is able to do this is a valid question.

Comment: @Flater - in an ideal world, the OP would use notification handlers, and everything would just work. (Even behaviors may fit the bill depending on the case.) I should have probably asked the OP for some pseudo code before answering. But what the OP asks in this question (i.e. to have multiple request handlers for a single request) does not make sense.